# How to calculate and redistribute Numeric Values between multiple Dataframes in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to figure out how to redistribute numerical values between multiple dataframes based on certain criteria, I am not sure exactly how to go about it.

For this purpose I have created 3 small sample DataFrames.

```
import pandas as pd

first = {'id_1': ['a','b','c'],
         'stock_1': [7,2,3]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(first, columns = ['id_1','stock_1'])

print(df1)

second = {'id_2': ['a','b','c'],
         'stock_2': [1,2,6]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(second, columns = ['id_2','stock_2'])

print(df2)

third = {'id_3': ['a','b','c'],
         'stock_3': [5,6,1]}

df3 = pd.DataFrame(third, columns = ['id_3','stock_3'])

print(df3)

   id_1  stock_1
0    a        7
1    b        2
2    c        3

  id_2  stock_2
0    a        1
1    b        2
2    c        6

  id_3  stock_3
0    a        5
1    b        6
2    c        1
```

Now I am trying to figure out how to write a function which will crosscheck all values for all 3 items and redistribute them in a way that it looks for MAX and MIN (a,b,c) and then subtracts from MAX and adds to MIN until AVG.

I would like resulting tables to look something like

```
  id_1  stock_1
0    a        4
1    b        3
2    c        3

  id_2  stock_2
0    a        4
1    b        3
2    c        4

  id_3  stock_3
0    a        5
1    b        4
2    c        3
```

If we are looking at Item 'a' in all 3 dataframes we get values; 7, 1, 5
with 7 being the MAX and 1 being the MIN.

AVG when roundup is (7+1+5)/3 = 4

so in order to add the correct amount to MIN we need to know the difference between AVG and MIN

(AVG - MIN) = (4-1) = 3 lets call it DIF

so I guess we have to add DIF to MIN

(DIF + MIN) = (3+1) = 4

and subtract DIF from MAX to get new values

(MAX - DIF) = (7-3) = 4

Comment: Can you please give an example of the output?

Comment: Hi, I edited the question with the desird output

Comment: Still do not understand the line "crosscheck all values for all 3 items and redistribute them in a way that it looks for MAX and MIN (a,b,c) and then subtracts from MAX and adds to MIN until AVG.". Could you please elaborate on the question with some formula calculation leading from 7 to 4 as output for the first data frame ?

Comment: I expanded the question

Answer (score 0):

First thing we need to do is get all the data in one place. For convenience, I would start with setting the index for each `DataFrame`, but you can get around that if it's really important to you.

```
df1.set_index('id_1',inplace=True)
df2.set_index('id_2',inplace=True)
df3.set_index('id_3',inplace=True)
```

To get all the data together, we simply join everything:

```
joined = df1.join(df2).join(df3)
print(joined)
```

This prints:

```
      stock_1  stock_2  stock_3
id_1                           
a           7        1        5
b           2        2        6
c           3        6        1
```

For convenience, I will transpose the matrix (this allow the usage of default axis for operations)

```
final_df = joined.T
```

For your specific computation, you can simply add the results of `min`,`max` and `mean`, for example:

```
diff = final_df.mean().round()-final_df.min()
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I understand indexing,  joins, etc. I guess I should start figuring out a loop which will evenutaly compute this for all 'items' (a,b,c) display results again as separate tables and a printed msg " 3 was added from df1'

Comment: No need. Once you have all the data in a single `DataFrame`, `joined`, then you can get your formula by using functions provided in pandas.